# How negative lookahead works

Tags: regex

I want to match a string not containing word "the"
The following solution looks logical to me:

```
^(?!.*the.*).*$
```

The following one (I've came across on SO) also works but I cannot understand WHY it works

```
^((?!the).)*$
```

In my view (?!the). should match a)ANY b)single character then repeatd by *, so the regex should match any string?
There is the great site I'm using for reference http://www.rexegg.com but no such example there

Comment: i think both won't work as you expect. why `weather` should failed on both expressions?

Comment: yes. I don't care about word boundaries here

Answer (score 1):

It's basically doing a match-any-character, and search for the string literal "the" in every position. If found, the negation cancels the match.

```
^            # Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
(            # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   (?!          # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
      the          # Match the characters “the” literally
   )
   .            # Match any single character that is not a line break character
)*           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$            # Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?!the).)*$
```

This will check at every point before consuming if there is `the` ahead of it.So in a string `abcthe` after `c` regex engine will see `the` and it will fail.But because you have `^$` anchors because the the engine could not make a complete match it will fail and not match anything.If you remove `$` it will match upto `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works but only if you also want to match strings not containing words with the characters `the` in them -- e.g., `I was going there` would be excluded. You need word boundaries if you want to match everything not containing the *word* `the`:

```
^((?!\bthe\b).)*$
```

or:

```
^(?!.*\bthe\b).*$
```